# hosting redirect through .htaccess to a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

So I have a hosting account that requires you to use a domain to represent your root and then all sub-domains are in the domain folder, that seems like a programmers nightmare. so here is what I need to know is there a way to put an html or .htaccess file in the root alongside all of my subdomain folders that will direct www.example.com to www.example.com/organizedfile and show www.example.com in the url bar so that it doesnt look like a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Imo you should use `mod_rewrite` in your `.htaccess` files.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html